# Angular 2 child to parent communication without using Event Emmiter

Tags: angular

I have a landing page. I need to load a login component using router.navigate([./app-login]) from landing page. After login success, from the same landing page i need to load the dashboard component using router.navigate. How to communicate login success to landing without event emitter?

My aim is to load login and dashboard view using router.navigate from the Landing view itself. Is it possible or Is this a right approach? 
If there is any other way please share..

landing.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    //directly navigate to login if token expired / first login
    this.router.navigate(['/app-login']);
}

loadDashdoard(){
    //load dashboard on success login
    this.router.navigate(['/app-dashboard']);
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the angular router. It solves the parent/child problem.

Lets say this is your landing page:

```
<h1>My Landing Page</h1>
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet>Your landing page / Login content will go here</router-outlet>
```

See the `<router-outlet>` tag? That's where the routed content will be loaded by the routing.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

In your case, you need to configure the both the landing-page content and the login component as your main landing-page's child.

```
const landingPageRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'landing-page',
    component: LandingPageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: LandingPageContentComponent            
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent            
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

You'll need a separate router for the dashboard. It's good to have separate routers for each group of functionality inside your angular application. And in this lets say DashboardRouter, you'll have to set the CanActivate attribute to an AuthGuard which you'll have to implement to say how your application's authorization works.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#guards

I guess you got the point, right?

Anyway, angular has a good documentation around routers and guards. That's the path to follow to solve your problem.